# How to change semantic-ui react Grid.Column padding

Tags: reactjs, grid, padding, semantic-ui

Is there a way to change the rather large top and bottom padding in Semantic-UI Grid?

Here an example code that produced a top and bottom padding of 1rem:

```js
import {Grid} from 'semantic-ui-react';

{/* ... */}

 <Grid container={true} relaxed>
            <Grid.Column >
                <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
            </Grid.Column>
{/* ... */}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately did not find an build-in option but this worked:

```js
import {Grid} from 'semantic-ui-react';

{/* ... */}

 <Grid container={true} relaxed><Grid container={true} className={'narrow'} relaxed>
            <Grid.Column >
                <h3>TEST TEST</h3>
            </Grid.Column>
{/* ... */}
```

with the following CSS:

```css
.ui.grid.narrow >.column:not(.row) {
    padding-top: 0.2rem !important;
    padding-bottom: 0.2rem !important;
}
```